# File caching vs mySQL storage of Twitter/Facebook/Other API results

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, caching, twitter

I have a few sites with Twitter & Facebook Feeds, and one that references a health club schedule (quite large, complicated data tree). I am starting to get into caching to improve load times on page, and am also interested in keeping bandwidth usage down as these sites are hosted on our own VPS.

Right now I have Twitter and Facebook serializing/unserializing each to a simple data file, rewriting themselves every 10 minutes. Would it be better to write this data to the mySQL database? And if so, what is a good method for accomplishing this?

Also, on the Twitter feed results, it contains only what I need, so it is nice and small (3 most recent tweets). But for Facebook, the result is larger and I sort through it with PHP for display - should I store THAT result or the raw feed? Does it matter?

For the other, larger JSON object, would the file vs mysql recommendation be the same?

I appreciate any insights and would be happy to show an example of the JSON schedule object if it makes a difference.

P.S. APC is not a viable option as it seemed to break all my WordPress installs yesterday. However, we are running on FastCGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a cache I would go for a file, but I don't think it will really matter. Unless ofcourse you have thousands or millions of these cache files, then mysql should be the way to go.  If you are doing anything else with the cache (like storing multiple versions or searching in the text) then I would go for MySQL.

As for speed, only cache what you're using. So the store the processed results and not the raw ones. Why process it every time? Try to cache it in a format as close as the actual output will be.

Since you use a VPS, I don't think you'll have an enormous amount of visitors so APC (although very nice) isn't really needed. If you do want a memory cache, you could try to look at xcache:
http://xcache.lighttpd.net/